# Typescript: property type based on property value

Tags: typescript

It's possible set a property type based on property value?

An example, if command is:

- 'set' payload must be PayloadSet
- 'put' payload must be PayloadPut
- 'del' payload must be PayloadDel

Now the closest solution i found is:

```
export interface Command {
    command: 'set' | 'put' | 'del';
    payload: PayloadSet | PayloadPut | PayloadDel;
}
```

but this allow user to set a command and set a wrong payload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Design it as a union:

```
type Command =
    | { command: 'set'; payload: PayloadSet; } 
    | { command: 'put'; payload: PayloadPut; } 
    | { command: 'del'; payload: PayloadDel; }
```

Comment: You can also play with conditional types with this, to be able to let the user pick a command like this `Command<'put'>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do some fancy stuff with conditional types, by adding a generic to the Command interface:

```
interface PayloadDel { }
interface PayloadPut {}
interface PayloadSet {}

type Commands = 'set' | 'put' | 'del'
export interface Command<K extends Commands> {
    command: K;
    payload: K extends 'set' ? PayloadSet : K extends 'put' ? PayloadPut : PayloadDel;
}

let command: Command<'set'>
```

This way the type depends on the type of `K`